# How to set a random color for each group of elements looping through an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set a different colors using jquery on each `.elements`, their children (`.element`) should have the same color but the attribution of color should be random for each `.elements`. How can I do it ?

Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/auscpzy6/6/

**Html**

```
<div class="elements"> <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">1</div> <!-- exmaple : red -->
  <div class="element">2</div> <!-- exmaple : red -->
</div>

<div class="elements"> <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">3</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">4</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">5</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>

<div class="elements"> <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">6</div> <!-- exmaple : yellow -->
</div>

<div class="elements"> <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">7</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">8</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>
```

**Javascript :** This is what I tried but everything stay on the same color.

```
function eachEl(el){
    var items = ["blue", "red", "yellow"];
    var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
    $(el).css({
        "color": item,
    });
}

$(".elements").each(function() {
    eachEl('.element');
});
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you need to loop through the `.elements`, choose a random colour from the array then set colour on that element.

The issue with your code was in the final part, as you were providing a selector which retrieved all the `.elements` to perform the `css()` call on, instead of the current one in the iteration. Try this, and note the use of `this` within the each loop to amend each specific element:

```js
$(".elements").each(function() {
  var items = ["blue", "red", "yellow"];
  var colour = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  $(this).css('color', colour);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elements">
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <div class="element">2</div>
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <div class="element">5</div>
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <div class="element">6</div>
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <div class="element">7</div>
  <div class="element">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, another question, is this the best way to do it performance wise? I see that it takes a bit of time to load, and I'm afraid that on a quantity of 200 elements it might get laggy.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance then I'd suggest avoiding jQuery completely. Looping through the DOM directly will be much, much faster, although there will always be speed issues if you have lots of elements in the DOM to cycle through

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are passing `'.element'` instead of `$(this)`, this should works:

```
function eachEl(el) {
  var items = ["blue", "red", "yellow"];
  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  $(el).css({
    "color": item,
  });
}

$(".elements").each(function() {
  eachEl($(this));
});
```

Comment: `eachEl(this)` would be enough, and avoid double-wrapping the jQuery object

Comment: You could also have unique colors by removing the color from the array after applying. Check my answer for one step further.

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa the OP states that duplicate colours are fine; they list `blue` twice in the HTML comments. In fact, duplicates have to be ok as there are 4 groups, but only 3 colour options

Comment: Yes I know, its just some extra knowledge on how to, which never hurts :)

Answer (score 1):

You could passing with `$(this)` instead of `.element` in `eachEl` function , change like this `eachEl($(this))`

```js
function eachEl(el) {
  var items = ["blue", "red", "yellow"];
  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  $(el).css({
    "color": item,
  });
}

$(".elements").each(function() {
  eachEl($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <!-- exmaple : red -->
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <!-- exmaple : red -->
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">5</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">6</div>
  <!-- exmaple : yellow -->
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">7</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">8</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass `eachEl(this)` instead of `eachEl('.element')` and then set color of all children of `el` to randomly selected color;

```js
function eachEl(el) {
  var items = ["blue", "red", "yellow"];
  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  $(el).children('.element').css({
    "color": item,
  });
}

$(".elements").each(function() {
  eachEl(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <!-- exmaple : red -->
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <!-- exmaple : red -->
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">5</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">6</div>
  <!-- exmaple : yellow -->
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">7</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">8</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `eachEl('.element');` you need to use `eachEl($(this).find('.element'));`. Your code was taking elements that have class as `element` but you need only child `element` of the current `elements`.

```js
function eachEl(el) {
  var items = ["blue", "red", "yellow"];
  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  $(el).css({
    "color": item,
  });
}

$(".elements").each(function() {
  eachEl($(this).find('.element'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">1</div>
  <!-- exmaple : red -->
  <div class="element">2</div>
  <!-- exmaple : red -->
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">3</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">4</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">5</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">6</div>
  <!-- exmaple : yellow -->
</div>

<div class="elements">
  <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">7</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">8</div>
  <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers provided are correct, where you need to just replace `'.element'` with `this`. But I will take it one step further also to show how to get **unique color for each** `element` div.

**Solution:** Just **remove the color from the array** once applied, so it does not apply again.

```
function eachEl(el) {
  var items = ["blue", "red", "yellow"];
  var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
  $(el).css({
    "color": item,
  });
  items.splice(items.indexOf(item), 1); //remove the color just applied
}

$(".elements").each(function() {
  eachEl(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ChangeColorCtrl($) {
  const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green'];
  
  return $('.elements')
    .each((i, group) => {
      const background = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
      
      return $(group)
        .each((j, child) => $(child).css({background}))
      ;
    })
  ;
}

jQuery(document).ready(ChangeColorCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elements"> <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">1</div> <!-- exmaple : red -->
  <div class="element">2</div> <!-- exmaple : red -->
</div>

<div class="elements"> <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">3</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">4</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">5</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>

<div class="elements"> <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">6</div> <!-- exmaple : yellow -->
</div>

<div class="elements"> <!-- children share the same color -->
  <div class="element">7</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
  <div class="element">8</div> <!-- exmaple : blue -->
</div>
```

Comment: it is not random

Comment: it was just an example on how to share bg among children.